# error in the word Database

Tags: android, database, eclipse

I downloaded the project and when I am trying to run on my eclipse its showing error in every line where the word "Database" is used...
so could you please help me with the possible fixes!
This is My Code:

```
public void createTables(SQLiteDatabase database) {
    String subscriber_table_sql = "create table " + Database.SUBSCRIBE_TABLE_NAME + " ( " +
            Database.SUBSCRIBE_ID   + " integer  primary key autoincrement," + 
            Database.SUBSCRIBE_NAME + " TEXT," +
            Database.SUBSCRIBE_PHONE + " TEXT," +
            Database.SUBSCRIBE_DEVICEID  + " TEXT," +
            Database.SUBSCRIBE_AREA + " TEXT," +
            Database.SUBSCRIBE_CITY + " TEXT)";


    String friends_table_sql = "create table " + Database.FRIENDS_TABLE_NAME + " ( " +
            Database.FRIENDS_ID     + " integer  primary key autoincrement," + 
            Database.FRIENDS_NAME + " TEXT," +
            Database.FRIENDS_PHONE + " TEXT," +
            Database.FRIENDS_AREA+ " TEXT," +
            Database.FRIENDS_CITY + " TEXT)";
```

Comment: What *is* the error?

Comment: I think Database is another class which you have not used or not imported, I am not sure but search in the downloaded project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

create a separate class called database inside the same package and declare the string variables such as FRIENDS_ID,FRIENDS_NAME

```
public class Database {
    static String FRIENDS_ID="friend_id",FRIENDS_NAME="friend_name",FRIENDS_PHONE="friend_phone",FRIENDS_AREA="friend_area",FRIENDS_CITY="friend_city";
  static String SUBSCRIBE_ID="subscribe_id",SUBSCRIBE_NAME="subscribe_name",SUBSCRIBE_PHONE="subscribe_phone",SUBSCRIBE_DEVICEID="subscribe_deviceid",SUBSCRIBE_AREA="subscribe_area",SUBSCRIBE_CITY="subscribe_city";

}
```

Comment: its still showing error in such lines like 
String subscriber_table_sql = "create table " + Database.SUBSCRIBE_TABLE_NAME 
and
String friends_table_sql = "create table " + Database.FRIENDS_TABLE_NAME
 
where the error is "Database.SUSCRIBE_TABLE_NAME" AND " DATABASE.FRIENDS_TABLE_NAME"

Comment: create a field for SUBSCRIBE_TABLE_NAME ,FRIENDS_TABLE_NAME ,SUSCRIBE_TABLE_NAME,FRIENDS_TABLE_NAME in database class